# I want to extract string from response body by regular expression in regular expression extractor in JMeter

Tags: regex, jmeter, expression, extractor

I have `nonce=nmjs7avwT1&` in the response body.

I want only the `nmjs7avwT1` part from above for the next request.

How can I write a regular expression for this?

Comment: `(?<=nonce=)[^&]+(?=&)`

Comment: Does "nonce=" always exist in your string? Do you always want everything between the `=` and the `&`? Can the text you want include those characters?

Answer (score 3):

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns this nonce
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Name of created variable: anything meaningful, i.e. `nonce`
   - Regular Expression: `nonce=(\w+)&`
   - Template: `$1$`
3. That's it, you should be able to refer the extracted value as `${nonce}` where required.

Demo (assumes [RegExp Tester mode of the View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script))

[image]

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expresssions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)